# How can i do an insert into a table of my DB that has one attribute of ADT type? with Oracle Live SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table for seeing how many people could die from COVID-19 in Latin country's for that i created an ADT structure which have two attributes `probabilidad_fallecidos` that means probability to death and `cantidad_infectados` that is the quantity of infected per country, The part i'm having problems is when i try to do an insert says `ORA-00947: not enough values`

I'm very new at this, this is my first try

Below i will let my ADT structure,my function, my table and my try of insert

***ADT***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE infectados AS OBJECT(
    cantidad_infectados number,
    probabilidad_fallecidos number,
    STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,probabilidad_fallecidos number) RETURN number
);
```

***Function `cantidad_fallecidos`***

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY infectados IS 
    STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,probabilidad_fallecidos number) RETURN number
    IS numero1 number(1);
        BEGIN
            IF cantidad_infectados > probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados THEN
                RETURN (probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados);
            ELSE
                RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR(-2000,'Error: cantidad_infectados es menor a la probabilidad de fallecidos');
            END IF;
        END;
    END;
```

***Creation of my table***

```sql
CREATE TABLE Vnzla_infectado(
    vnzlaInf_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    num_infectados infectados
);
```

***Try of insert***

```sql
INSERT INTO Vnzla_infectado 
VALUES (infectados(100,0.1,infectados.cantidad_fallecidos(100,0.1)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error `ORA-00947: not enough values` because you are supplying one value to insert into a table with two columns, and you are not specifying which column you are trying to insert into so Oracle thinks you are inserting into all columns.

Your `vnzlaInf_id` column may be generated by an `IDENTITY`, but it looked to the database as if you were attempting to insert a value into that column and nothing into the `num_infectados` column, hence the error about not enough values.

So the first thing you need to do is to modify the `INSERT` statement to tell the database which column you want to insert into:

```sql
INSERT INTO Vnzla_infectado (num_infectados) 
VALUES ...
```

I wrote "first thing" because there is another problem with your `INSERT` statement.  If you add that column name, you get another error, `ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor`.  This is because your type constructor has two arguments, but you are specifying three.  One way to fix it is to get rid of the third argument:

```sql
INSERT INTO Vnzla_infectado (num_infectados) 
VALUES (infectados(100,0.1));
```

This `INSERT` statement runs successfully.

Alternatively, you may want to add another field to your type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE infectados AS OBJECT(
    cantidad_infectados number,
    probabilidad_fallecidos number,
    your_new_field_name_here number,
    STATIC FUNCTION cantidad_fallecidos(cantidad_infectados number,probabilidad_fallecidos number) RETURN number
);
```

If you are going to change the type, you will have to drop the table first and recreate it afterwards.  After doing this, your original `INSERT` statement runs fine.

While I'm here, there are some other problems I noticed with your static function `cantidad_fallecidos`.  Firstly, there is a typo in `RAISE_APLICATION_ERROR`, it should be `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` - you're missing one of the `P`s.  Secondly, the argument `-2000` will get rejected by Oracle: it will complain with `ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of -2000 is out of range` if you attempt to raise your custom error.  I guess you meant to use `-20000` for the error number instead.  Thirdly, the condition

```sql
cantidad_infectados > probabilidad_fallecidos*cantidad_infectados
```

looks a bit odd to me.  Provided `cantidad_fallecidos` is greater than zero, then it is equivalent to

```sql
1 > probabilidad_fallecidos
```

Also, are you sure you need to use `>` rather than `>=`?  This leads to some odd behaviour in unusual cases: if `cantidad_infectados` is zero, your condition will never be true and your custom error will be raised whatever `probabilidad_fallecidos` is. To me it makes more sense to validate that `probabilidad_fallecidos` is between 0 and 1.

Comment: You were right i saw that my problem now is on my function